# How can I show at least 3 record from mysql using php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been search for a while regarding my problem and did not find a similar problem with mine :( then I decided to write this, I apologize if this question seem similar. I had a problem to showing at least 3 record from mysql using PDO, I'm really newbie in php and just trying to make a testimonial page driven in PHP and MySQL database, here is my code -

```
<?php
require_once('conf.php');

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    foreach($conn->query('SELECT title, name, visit, rating, review, recommended, rev_date, COUNT(id) as count, ROUND(AVG(rating),1) as t_rating FROM bike_tour WHERE published=1 LIMIT 0, 3') as $row) {
 $vote = $row["count"]; $score = $row["t_rating"]; $star_p = ($score/5)*100 . '%';
            echo'<div class="tab-pane fade" id="reviews">';
                echo'<div class="intro table-wrapper full-width hidden-table-sms">';
                    echo'<div class="rating table-cell col-sm-4">';
                        echo'<span class="score">' .$score. '/5.0</span>';
                        echo'<div class="five-stars-container"><div class="five-stars" style="width:'.$star_p.';"></div></div>';
                        echo'<a href="#" class="goto-writereview-pane button green btn-small full-width">WRITE A REVIEW</a>';
                    echo'</div>';
                    echo'<div class="table-cell col-sm-8">';
                        echo'<div class="detailed-rating">';
                            echo'</div>';
                    echo'</div>';
                echo'</div>';
              echo'<div class="guest-reviews">';
                  echo'<h2>Guest Reviews</h2>';
                      echo'<div class="guest-review table-wrapper">';
                          echo'<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 author table-cell">';
                              echo'<i class="soap-icon-conference yellow-color" style="font-size: 4em;"></i>';
                                  echo'<p class="name">' . $row["name"] . '</p>';
                                  echo'<p class="date">Visited: '. $row["visit"] .'</p>';
                                  echo'<p class="date">Reviewed: '. $row["rev_date"] . '</span></p>';
                              echo'</div>';
                              echo'<div class="col-xs-9 col-md-10 table-cell comment-container">';
                                  echo'<div class="comment-header clearfix">';
                                      echo'<h4 class="comment-title">' . $row["title"] . '</h4>';
                                      echo'<div class="review-score">';
                                          echo'<div class="five-stars-container"><div class="five-stars" style="width:'.$row['rating'].';"></div></div>';
                                          echo'<span class="score">' . $row["rating"] . '.0/5.0 </span>';
                                      echo'</div>';
                                  echo'</div>';
                                  echo'<div class="comment-content">';
                                      echo'<p>' . $row["review"] . '</p>';
                                      echo'<br>';
                                      echo'<p> Recommended: <span class="recommended">' . $row["recommended"] . '</span></p>';
                                  echo'</div>';
                              echo'</div>';
                          echo'</div>';
                        echo'</div>';
                      echo'</div>';

    }   
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

but this just return only 1 record, I have 5 sample records in my db and wish to show 3 of them. Could you guys help me please? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: `$result = $conn->query("SELECT....")->fetchAll(); foreach($result as $record)....` - that's how. Also, if you want to limit the results to a certain number, then use `SELECT col FROM table LIMIT 3`. No need to reinvent hot water.

Comment: Maybe there is only one row that matches your search criteria!! The limit does not force the returning of 3 rows, it just limits it to 3 if there are more than 3

Comment: You have to set the OFFSET (you did it) but dont put it in the loop. BTW this is the most horrible PHPHTML that I've ever seen. Think about data layers.

Comment: @Mjh 1) His foreach is fine. No need for the fetchall. 2) OP already uses LIMIT in their SQL.

Comment: Did you try running your raw SQL query directly into PhpMyAdmin or in CLI? Just to be sure you actually get at least 3 results.

Comment: @MichaëlGarrez I did it, but still the same return only one record

Comment: @bub Sorry as I'm just a newbie, I hope I can learn from here. Anyway, thanks guys for answering :)